# Is "pointer to const int" same as " const int* "

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, auto

I am reading about pointers and got confused in one part. The code given is as follows:

```cpp
int i=0;
const int ci = i;
auto *p = &ci;`
```

Now the question is what will be the type of `p`? I am thinking that `p` will be a **pointer to const int**. Is this correct? And if yes will this be equal to **const int***? Is a pointer to `const int` the same as `const int*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the `const` keyword generally applies to the part of the type to its left.

So `int const*` is a pointer to a constant integer, and `int*const` is a constant pointer to a non-constant integer.

The type of `p` in your example is a `int const*`.

The habit of putting `const` to the right is known as east const.

Now there is an exception to the "const applies to the left"; when there is **nothing** to the left, it applies to the right instead.  This confusing exception means that `const int*` is `int const*`.  But `using X=int*; const X` becomes `int*const`.

The habit of putting `const` on the left, and the resulting confusion, is known as west const.

In short, the answer is yes, unless you add aliases.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am thinking that p will be a **pointer to const int**.*

Yes, that's what `p` will be.

> *And if yes will this be equal to `const int*`?*

Yes: `const int* p;` is exactly how you define `p` as a pointer to a `const int`.

Just in case you're wondering, you can define/initialize a `const` pointer to a (non-const) `int` as follows:

```
int* const cp = &i;
```

And, for a `const` pointer to a `const int`, you would need the `const` qualifier twice:

```cpp
const int* const cp = &ci;
```